# solution verification for evaluating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{|\frac{1}{2}-\sin^2x|}$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

I have to evaluate

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{|\frac{1}{2}-\sin^2x|\mathrm dx}$$

**What I've got:**

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left|\frac{1}{2}-\sin^2x\right|\mathrm dx}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left|\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}\right|\mathrm dx}=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left|\cos2x\right|\mathrm d(2x)}$$

The $\cos x$ is positive from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so I guess taking the absolute value is the same as just taking the value.

$$I=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos2x\,\mathrm d(2x)}=\frac{1}{4}(\sin{\pi}-\sin{0})+C=C-\frac{1}{4}$$

Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}|\cos2x|dx=\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos2x\ dx+\int_{{\pi/4}}^{\pi/2}(-\cos2x)\ dx$$

As $\cos2x\le0$ for $\dfrac\pi2\le2x\le\pi$

Comment: Oh, I see. $cosx$ is positive from 0 to $\pi/2$ but $cos2x$ goes to the negative values.

Comment: @Nikola, $$|a|=\begin{cases} a &\mbox{if } a>0 \\
-a & \mbox{if } a\le0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Of course, that was kind of stupid. Thank you!